# How to solve merge conflict of file renamed in Github

Tags: git, github

While working into my branch, I have renamed a file (lets call it `/documents/FILE.pyc` to `documents/FILE.py`) and after submitting the pull request, `Git` is saying `This branch has conflicts that must be resolved` using the `command line` and unable the ability to resolve the conflict from the github interface. (Which is the way I mostly solve conflicts on github)

Now I have to use the `command line` as per `github` before continuing.

What is the best way to solve this?

A walkthrough would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is the same as what you do to solve all merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to your problem:

1) From the command line, you need to make a git rebase https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

2) From GitHub, you can make the pull request and solve the conflicts there

Comment: Hi Oscar. Thanks, Can you elaborate what you mean by `make the pull request` in option 2? I am currently still in the personal branch and used `visual studio code` to browse into the folder where the file was renamed but since it is a `file` not just lines of codes. I dont see how to solve it.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, you can enter GitHub go to branches, and create a pull request. If there's any issue with the merging GitHub will notify you there and you can solve the contact directly on the page

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, in command prompt you have to do `git pull` the  branch where you are getting this error.

Then after that, fix the conflicts which is shown in your command prompt then you can push them using `git push`.

The above pull or push command may vary according to the way how you created the branch.( two ways of creating branch, one is from command prompt and another is from github directly)

The above commands will work if you create branch in github directly otherwise you have to do `git pull origin master` to pull and `git push origin master` to push. Before that you will have to set origin.

Comment: after using `git pull origin master` and solving the conflict on `visual studio code`. now when i do `git add -A` and check the files `git status` I have a LOOOONG list of files + the one change I just made to solve the conflict. Do you think that If I push the LOOONG List of files will be included or just the one file i modified?

Comment: can you see what are the changes happened in these LONG list of files ?just check once

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it thus

git stash # this will save your changes to a temp stash
git pull  # this will bring the server changes 
git stash pop # this will prompt the required screen to locally solve the conflict